# How to fetch API at component level and prerender it in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

We need to populate the list of links in the footer component But these methods `getInitialProps`, `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` are not getting executed in the `footer` component. Here is the code:

```
const Layout = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
                {props.children}
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}
export default Layout;
```

--- Footer Component ---

```
    const Footer = ({data}) => {
    return(
        <ul>
            {data && data.map((todo,index)=>{
               return <li key={index}>
                    {todo.title}
                </li>
            })}
        </ul>
    );
}
export async function getStaticProps() {   // not working with getInitialProps and getServerSideProps as well
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {data}
  }
}
export default Footer;
```

EDIT: `Footer` component should not displayed in Login/Signup pages.

In the _app.js, i have passed the data as `<Component {...pageProps} footerData={...data} />` but the data object is not available in Footer component.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @NileshPatel im not getting any error, these above methods are not getting executed.

Comment: where have you used `Layout` component.. in `_app.js`??

Comment: @NileshPatel `Layout` component is wrapped in each page therefore, for homepage its in index.page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getInitialProps`, `getServerSideProps`, and `getStaticProps` just only run on top of the page, not component.

If you want to run fetch on `Footer`, you can call fetch function on `useEffect` hook, or simply call fetch in one of the `getInitialProps`, `getServerSideProps`, and `getStaticProps` on top of the page (i.e such as _index.js) and pass down Footer by props.

You also can use getInitialsProps on top application in `_app.js`;

```
import App, {Container} from 'next/app'
import React from 'react'
import Footer from 'somewhere/Footer';

export default class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps ({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}
    let data = await fetch('/api');
    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return {data, pageProps}
  }

  render () {
    const {Component, pageProps, data} = this.props
    return <Container>
      <Component {...pageProps} footerData={data} />
    </Container>
  }
}
```

and FooterComponent look like this

```
 export const Footer = ({data}) => {
    return(
        <ul>
            {data && data.map((todo,index)=>{
               return <li key={index}>
                    {todo.title}
                </li>
            })}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

on the pages except Login, Signup which need Footer component (Home/index.tsx, User/index.tsx)

```
export const Home = ({footerData}) = {
   return <div>
       <Header/>
       <Footer data={footerData} />
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Since Footer component appears in all the pages, i cant fetch the api only in index.js. Im looking for more generic solution. And the data needs to be prerendered to improve the SEO, therefore, i cant use `useEffect`

Comment: I think this solution is better. Since Footer appears on all page, let's place Footer on _app.js (on top application) and use getInitialProps to fetch API and pass down to Footer component.

Comment: Okay, Could you share the code snippet of _app.js with getinitialprops so that I will accept it as answer.

Comment: You can try my solution. I updated my answer.

Comment: Footer component should not appear in login and signup pages. In your solution, footer component is appearing in all pages.

Comment: You told me they appear on all page :) so I think just one way to do this. put Footer on pages needed, and still fetch data once in _app.js and pass down to components

Comment: Okay, i tried the way you suggested. I removed the footer component and passed the data to the `component`. but the data is not available in the footer component. I have updated the question please have a look.

Comment: You can look at my solution again, I have just updated my comment. Put Footer on all pages needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227340/discussion-between-cuongdevjs-and-code-knight).